# 128 bit reversible encryptor/hasher to reduce DB size

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hash, md5

Is there anything out there for PHP that can hash/encrypt a long string into a 128 bit string that can also be reversed?

I am trying importing hundreds on millions of strings into a MySQL DB and the average string is over 100 characters, MD5 gets this down to 32 characters which significantly reduces storage however I cannot reverse this again in my application.

Does PHP have anything available that can handle this?

Comment: By definition, hashing is irreversible; so you're looking at encryption; but no encryption scheme can reduce an arbitrary length string to a fixed (128bit) size without losing information

Comment: `hundreds on millions of strings... and the average string is over 100 characters` Is disk space really so expensive?

Comment: You call that compression…

Comment: The DB is expected to grow to hundreds of billions of strings, I'm not even confident MySQL is the right DB for the job however I would like to test it, and getting strings down in size would be beneficial

Comment: it has NOTHING to do with encrytion, hashing, etc... but have a look here... http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

Comment: If you have billions of strings of length 100 bytes, you may want to look into de-duplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication.

Comment: If any of the given answers solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) one of them. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems to me you mix up hashing and compression quite a lot.

Most hash-functions are not easily reversible, because that is not their purpose. There are infinite "Strings/ByteStreams/Numbers/..." that correspond to the result of a hash-function. As you may know, even images that are a few Gigabytes big, also give you an md5sum of 32 characters.

You can not just magically map any String into a String of fixed length that is shorter, to just be able to magically pouff it back to its original String.

It may well be, that some hash-functions could very efficiently be used to reverse their process if you know that your target results have to have this and that property (in you case maybe character-length of 100-120), but I doubt it.

Or do I totally misunderstand and you just mean ASCII-Strings with the expression "128 bit string"?

Comment: not easily reversible... you mean not reversible at all... what you can find for a hash is a collision ... something that will result in a given hash ... but there are usually infinite elements resulting in the same hash with no way of telling wich one was used to create the hash in the beginning

Comment: yep i have mixed up hashing and compression, compression is what im looking for, I will research compression on MySQL. thanks

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: Yeah, thanks. That is what I was trying to describe.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this: [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)